# Blender make my glTF file a lot bigger

Tags: gltf

I have a 193Mb file in .glb format that I exported from Reality Capture (photogrammetry)

When I import it in Blender, the only thing I modify is the orientation. I rotate the model from upside down to upright down and that's absolutely all I do. When I export the model back in .glb, it goes from 193Mb to 1.06 Gb. Is there any reason to that? How can I avoid this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: There could be many reasons, [eg](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1166). It's impossible to know why without knowing more about your model though. Try turning off export settings like UVs, normals, vertex colors, materials, etc. one by one to see if you can isolate what the problem is.

Comment: Apparently, when I turn off "normals" setting, it kind of works. It just make the file like 1.2-1.3 times bigger. I guess I can work with that ! Thanks a lot for your help!